# Adding multiple Schemas to a single servlet

Tags: java, servlets, xsd

I have two schemas and two endpoints, and currently i have only one servlet. Is there a way I can add both schemas to the one servlet? or do I have to add a second servlet.

Other possibilities ive seen involve combining two two scemas into one schema, my problemn here is I would not want people to be able to see the content of the second schema. What would be the best way to go about this.

Any suggestions on this would be useful I have found suggesions but nothing to say what would be the best way to go about doing this.

Currently I have a single servlet that uses `simpleXsdSchema`

```
 <bean id="schema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema" 
        p:xsd = "classpath:au/test/Search/ws/schemas/Search.xsd"/>
```

i wanted to do something like this:

```
<bean id="schema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
    <property name="schema">
        <list>
            <value>
                classpath:au/test/Search/ws/schemas/Search.xsd
            </value>
            <value>
                classpath:au/test/Search/ws/schemas/admin/SearchAdmin.xsd
            </value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
*i am aware this does not work
```

but im not really sure if this is the right way to be going about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after more research multiple schema's can be declared using the schema collection class, need to import xmlschema framework.

```
<bean id="schemaCollection"
    class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">
    <property name="xsds">
        <list>
            <value>au/test/Search/ws/schemas/admin/SearchAdmin.xsd</value>
            <value>au/test/Search/ws/schemas/Search.xsd</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="inline" value="true" />
</bean>
```

for my case this was not the best method i found to do so instead declaring two servlets was the best course of action.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% of what you need, but in Servlets you can define multiple endpoints that point to the same servlet using your deployment descriptor (`web.xml`) like this :

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>Servlet.java</servlet-class>
</servlet>
....
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/endpoint1</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/endpoint2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then in the Servlet code you can define your application logic (if the request comes from `endpoint1` you can show different content than from coming from  `endpoint2` )

Comment: thanks for thte answer, i am aware that this is possible. I just didn't know what was the best way to do what i was after.